# Django templates iterate through list of tuples and give them all buttons

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a User model and the user's have university attribute. I want users to be able to scroll through a list of universities and choose one as a button, I don't want to have a dropdown selecter thing. So I passed in the `UserInfo.UNIVERSITY_CHOICES` (`UserInfo` is a one to one with the user model) to my template and try to iterate through it using:

```
<form method="get" action="/newUniversity/">
{% csrf_token %}

    {% for school in universityList %}
         <input class='submitbtn' type="submit" name="school" value="{{ school }}"></center>
    {% endfor %}
</form>
```

However I get a bunch of buttons that say `('Harvard','Harvard')` instead of just Harvard. I tried to index the tuple by doing `school[1]` but that gives me an error. Is there a way to do this or am I doing it a completely wrong way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `UserInfo.UNIVERSITY_CHOICES` is tuple (like the ones you would use with the django admin) you must choose which of the values you are after:

```
school.0
```

or

```
school.1
```

Notice Django's Template Language is not Python! You can see a reference of the language here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/

Comment: Give me 6 minutes and I can accept this as the answer. This is just a problem of me not knowing python very well. I thought you indexed tuples with brackets.

Comment: You do, but in this case you are actually using django's template language, not python itself. They are two different beasts: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/

Although django's template language tries to be somewhat similar to python, its way more restricted in what it can do.